# Failed to discover node in batman-adv

Tags: networking, mesh

I have installed batman-adv in 3 ubuntu machine with same essid and cell id.
2 out of 3 are able to discover each other and creating mesh network but the 3rd one is not able to discover.

difference here is, 2 working machine has batman-adv version 2016.3 where as 3rd machine has version batman-adv 2016.5

Is this the reason for the 3rd node to not able to discover in the network?
Can anyone tell me how to install a specific batman-adv version?

![screen shot for batman error in the 3rd node][1]

Comment: did you miss adding the screenshot?

Comment: stackexchange didnt allow me to add the screenshot :(
Error in the 3rd node is:
sudo batctl o
No interfaces added with batman (somthing like this)
but when i check the batman interface list, it shows me interface is active
sudo batctl if
wlp2s0: active

Answer (score 1):

i found the kernel version in my 3 ubuntu machines were different.
2 out of 3 had version 4.8.0-36 and the 3rd one had 4.10.0.
looks like, batman-adv version 2016.5 and kernel version 4.10.0 are not compatible with each other.
I was also not able to install 2016.3 version in kernel version 4.10.0.

Solution that I chose was, to downgrade the kernel version to 4.8.0-36 and make sure all the PCs has same kernel version.
Installed batman-adv and batctl version of 2016.3 from following link:
https://downloads.open-mesh.org/batman/releases/batman-adv-2016.3/

once the kernel and batman version of all 3 PCs are same, they are able to discover and create mesh between each other.